# PHP - enabling contained object access to container object information

Tags: php, oop

I have a compound object class which has a contained component class, and on instantiation I want the contained object to have real-time access to the compound object's methods and properties.

In the following example of "Car" and "Wheel" I have written, a dynamic relationship between diameter of Wheel and height of Car is established. Changing the height of the car automatically changes the diameter of the wheel appropriately, thus retaining the car's proportions:

```
class Car {
  private $wheel;
  private $heightM;

  function __construct() {
    $this->wheel = new Wheel($this);
  }

  final public function wheel() {
    return $this->wheel;
  }

  final public function setHeight($metres) {
    $this->heightM = $metres;
  }

  final public function height() {
    return $this->heightM;
  }

}

class Wheel {
  private $car;

  final public function __construct(Car &$car) {  // by reference
    $this->car = &$car;                           // pointer
  }

  final public function diameter() {
    return $this->car->height() * 20 / 100;
  }

}

$toyota = new Car();
$toyota->setHeight(1);
print "Car height = " . $toyota->height() . "m" 
      . "; Wheel diameter = " . $toyota->wheel()->diameter() . "m" 
      . PHP_EOL;
$toyota->setHeight(2);
print "Car height = " . $toyota->height() . "m" 
      . "; Wheel diameter = " . $toyota->wheel()->diameter() . "m" 
      . PHP_EOL;
```

which outputs:

```
Car height = 1m; Wheel diameter = 0.2m
Car height = 2m; Wheel diameter = 0.4m
```

This is exactly the result I want, however I am seeking guidance as to whether the above constitutes an acceptable PHP coding approach or whether there are better OOP/PHP approaches for achieving the same. Thanks!

**EDIT**: In an effort to make this question more specific: I am really looking for an answer such: NO - this approach will break PHP for reason A,B and C; or NO - please see formal design pattern X which is the recognised standard for achieving this functionality. Alternatively, YES - the use of pointers to achieve what you are trying to do here is perfectly acceptable (of course this is within the constraints that I do understand the risks pointers can present)

Comment: What is this for? At first look, it seems like a terrible idea. You are coupling what you're calling a "Container" class (i think you mean parent class) with a "Contained" (child class) class on seemingly zero grounds. initially i thought you may be talking about the "wrapper pattern" (google it), but i am lost now.

Comment: @jeremy - an applied example: Assume the container class is "Car" and the contained class is "Wheel", and that the diameter of Wheel needs to at all times remain proportional to the height of Car. Now assume $car->heightM() = 1 and $car->wheel()->diameterM() = 0.1. Using the above approach, running $car->setHeightM(2); will automatically result in $car->wheel()->diameterM() returning 0.2, thus achieving the desired behaviour. (and could likewise be used for many car components) However, if the approach is unsound, or there is a preferred PHP pattern for achieving the same, please do shout!

Comment: ah. i wouldn't call it 'container'/'contained'

Comment: @jeremy - I have edited the question to make it more "real world", hopefully enhancing clarity for the reader. If you have any comments please do shout. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your example, there is no need to pass `$car` by reference to `Wheel`'s constructor. What are you trying to achieve by passing it by reference?
2. Your code won't break PHP :)
3. One thing you may want to ask yourself is whether `Wheel` needs to have such intimate knowledge of the `Car` it belongs to.

For example: does it really need access to other (future?) `Car` properties such as its `maxSpeed`? Its `fuelConsumptionRate`? Its `price`?

Does it need access to its `startEngine()` and `parkHere()` functionalities?

Moreover, in the future, is it possible that you'd want to put `Wheel`s on other things, like `SupermarketShoppingCart` or `Rollerblades`?

Consider not having `Wheel` reference a `Car` at all. One thing you could do instead, is define an interface, say `IWheelOwner`, that would declare the properties and functionality that `Wheel`s are likely to expect from their owners. Then have `Car` implement that interface. Then, you can still pass `$car` down to `$wheel`, but treat it as an interface:

```
/** @var IWheelOwner */
private $wheelOwner;

final public function __construct(IWheelOwner $wheelOwner) {
    $this->wheelOwner = $wheelOwner;
}
```

4. You may want to consider doing it the other way around. You could have `Car` adjust the size of the `Wheel`s whenever its own height changes. If you consider the 20% ratio as a "`Wheel` knowledge" that the `Car` should be unaware of - simply give `Wheel` an `readjustDiameter($ownerHeight)` function and call it whenever the `Car`'s height is changed.

Comment: thanks @obe! The "reason" I was passing the parameter in "by reference" was as my understanding is that "call by value" creates "a copy" of the passed variable, so my pointer would be pointing at the copy and would thus not be affected by subsequent changes to the parent "Car". I have tested and I see that this is indeed not the case! (so thanks and I like this better as I'm not looking for the "wheel to wag the car" :) ). Re: Interfaces - yes 100%, I was just keeping simple for the illustration.

Comment: Re: too much visibility - I was looking at the concept more than the detail but it's a very valid point! I have just tested passing in "just what is needed" ie. in this case Car's $this->heightM property and setting the pointer to that. Interestingly I see that in this case one has to pass in the parameter by reference (in line with my understanding explained above) . ie. PHPs parameter handling approach does not appear to be entirely consistent. Not sure why.

Comment: This comment: "pointers to objects, not objects themselves, are passed to functions. These pointers are COPIES of the original unless you use "&" in your parameter list to actually pass the originals. Only when you dig into the internals of an object will the originals change" taken from http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php appears to explain the different object / simple variable behaviour when passed as parameters.

Comment: @Pancho - if I understand your second comment correctly, you experimented with passing a reference to the car's height property to the wheel. I wouldn't implement it like this because it breaks the car's encapsulation. It is good design to have all changes to an object's state go through setters; making objects interact by having them keep pointers to properties of each other is bad because it breaks decoupling, and could make maintenance of the code more difficult. With larger code bases, it's also prone to cause weird phenomena and hard-to-find bugs...

Comment: this is not the correct way to do this. see axiac's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, the `Car` class is not a [container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_(abstract_data_type)) but a [compound object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

A container is a collection of zero or more objects of the same type (or abstract type) but the contained objects may exist and work well even when they are not added to the container. Letting the contained objects know about the presence of the container makes them difficult (or even impossible) to be used without a container. It is obviously a bad practice.

A compound object is made of smaller objects (of simpler types), not necessarily all of them of the same type and their number is usually known in advance. The components are owned by the compound objects; they are destroyed when the compound object is destroyed. Letting the components know about their owner (the compound object) is sometimes useful but most of the times it is not needed.

You should think all the operations with `Car` and its components in a top-down manner. All its methods should query or modify its primitive properties (`$heightM`) directly and, if needed, call the methods of its components (`$wheel`) to query or modify them.

Only the `Car` object should be visible from the outside. It's bad design to expose its components for direct access (this is what your method `Car::wheel()` does).

```
class Car {
  private $wheel;
  private $heightM;

  function __construct($metres) {
    $this->wheel = new Wheel(0);
    $this->setHeight($metres);
  }

  final public function setHeight($metres) {
    $this->heightM = $metres;
    $this->wheel->setDiameter(0.2 * $metres);
  }

  final public function getHeight() {
    return $this->heightM;
  }

  public function getWheelDiameter() {
    return $this->wheel->getDiameter();
  }
}

class Wheel {
  private $diameter;

  final public function __construct($diameter) {
    $this->setDiameter($diameter);
  }

  final public function getDiameter() {
    return $this->diameter;
  }

  public function setDiameter($diameter) {
    $this->diameter = $diameter;
  }
}

$toyota = new Car(1);
print "Car height = " . $toyota->getHeight() . "m" 
      . "; Wheel diameter = " . $toyota->getWheelDiameter() . "m" 
      . PHP_EOL;
$toyota->setHeight(2);
print "Car height = " . $toyota->getHeight() . "m" 
      . "; Wheel diameter = " . $toyota->getWheelDiameter() . "m" 
      . PHP_EOL;
```

I tried to do the minimal changes to your code to show you how I would do it.

#### Improvements

Depending on how you plan to use these classes, it is probably better to make the `Wheel` class read-only (drop its `setDiameter()` method) and pass a `Wheel` object to the constructor of the `Car` object. Also I would remove the `setHeight()` method of class `Car`. A car's height changes when you change the wheel types or when you add accessories to it. All these actions should have their own methods. I would also change the implementation of `Car::getHeight()` to also use the wheel size.

```
class Car {
  private $height;
  private $wheel;

  public function __construct($height, Wheel $wheel) {
    $this->height = $height;
    $this->wheel  = $wheel;
  }

  public function changeWheelType(Wheel $wheel) {
    $this->wheel = $wheel;
  }

  public function getHeight() {
    // Implement the appropriate formula here
    return $this->height + $this->getWheelDiameter() / 2;
  }

  public function getWheelDiameter() {
    return $this->wheel->getDiameter();
  }
}

class Wheel {
  private $diameter;

  final public function __construct($diameter) {
    $this->diameter = $diameter;
  }

  final public function getDiameter() {
    return $this->diameter;
  }
}


$toyota = new Car(1, new Wheel(0.2));
print "Car height = " . $toyota->getHeight() . "m" 
  . "; Wheel diameter = " . $toyota->getWheelDiameter() . "m" 
  . PHP_EOL;

$toyota->changeWheelType(new Wheel(0.3));
print "Car height = " . $toyota->getHeight() . "m" 
  . "; Wheel diameter = " . $toyota->getWheelDiameter() . "m" 
  . PHP_EOL;
```

This way everything is clear. The wheel height doesn't change and the car height doesn't change either. But you can put wheels of a different size to the car and the total car height changes this way.

Comment: thanks @axiac - I was using the word "container" in the literal sense but I see I've hit a "reserved concept" :)  - thanks for letting me know. I've edited my post accordingly. Thanks also for the great pointers.

Answer (score -1):

They way i would go about it, is making a wheel a class with static functions. Php does not support multiple inheritance, and reference by pointer can get hectic if it is not apparent (just try looking at your code in 2 weeks).

```
class Car {
  private $heightM;

  final public function setHeight($metres) {
    $this->heightM = $metres;
  }

  final public function height() {
    return $this->heightM;
  }

  final public function wheel() {
    return Wheel::getWheel($this);
  }

}

class Wheel {
  public static function getWheel($car) {
    $wheel = [];
    $wheel["diameter"] = $car->height() * 20 / 100;
    return (object)$wheel;
  }

}

$toyota = new Car();
$toyota->setHeight(1);
print "Wheel diameter = " . $toyota->wheel()->diameter . "m" . PHP_EOL;
$toyota->setHeight(2);
print "Wheel diameter = " . $toyota->wheel()->diameter . "m" . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: thanks very much for your input! First a quick side note that PHP does actually offer a variant of multiple inheritance via traits. That being said I do not require multiple inheritance here. I do still prefer my approach above because, other than the 2 commented lines in the Wheel class constructor, the fact that a pointer is being used is completely abstracted from the code. (The same hold true for any number of SteeringWheel etc "contained" classes). Also, using arrays and strings wrecks code completion in the IDE which can make subsequent editing confusing. But thanks!

Comment: just a note that I did NOT downvote you! (and to whoever did downvote, stop being lazy and provide your rationale so that others can assess it. The whole purpose of this site is community growth through shared knowledge)